# Two overflow menus visible

Tags: android

I have two below menu items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never"
        />
</menu>
```

Overflow menu style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OptionsMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="OptionsMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

When the application is run, two overflow menus are visible: one upon clicking '3 dots' in the toolbar (styled as above, pops up in the upper right corner) and the other when menu button is clicked (default style, pops up in the bottom of the screen).

How to show only one of the menus - preferably the one that pops up in the upper right corner?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue like yours. and resolve with below code:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
          toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
          return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
 }
```